# The quality of binding sites?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling

Can someone please provide a human friendly explanation.

to the following:

> RNAp binds a defined site (a specific DNA sequence) at the promoter
> (Fig- ure 2.2a). The quality of this site specifies the transcription
> rate of the gene

what is the quality of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quality is most likely related to how tightly RNAp binds to conserved sequences in the promoter, and *that* is related to how closely the actual sequences themselves are to RNAp's "most-preferred" sequences. The actual sequences can vary between genes, giving them different transcription rates.

Comment: thank you for your explanation 
much appreciated